# MVVM: Change @State from Model

Tags: mvvm, swiftui

I am trying to learn SwiftUI and MVVM by coding a little game and ran into a problem.
I want to show popups once my model reached certain points. So I coded a popup with a @Binding var of type Bool that decides whether the popup is shown or not. My main view has an @State var showPopup that is "bonded" to the popup view.
To see if I got it right, I created a @Published var "test" in my viewmodel and put `.onReceive(viewModel.$test){show in showDrink = show}` behind my popup, which just works fine.
What I can't seem to figure out, is how to connect the var from my viewmodel to the model.

Here is the relevant part of my model:

```
    struct game {
    .
    .
        var modelShowPopup: Bool = false
    }
```

Here of my viewmodel:

```
    class game: ObservableObject{

        //@Published private var test: Bool = false <- just for testing 
        @Published private var model: game = game()

        var vmShowPopup: Bool{
            get {
                game.modelShowPopup
            }
            set(vmShowPopup) {
                game.modelShowPopup = vmShowPopup
            }
        }
```

and here of the view:

```
    struct BusDriverView: View {

        @ObservedObject var viewModel: BusDriver
        @State var showPopup: Bool = false
        
        var portraitLayout: some View{
            ZStack{
                deckbody
                // this worked: 
                popup(title: "", message: "", buttonText: "", show: $showPopup).onReceive(viewModel.$test){show in showPopup = show}
                // this gets me Error(Instance method 'onReceive(_:perform:)' requires that 'Binding<Bool>' conform to 'Publisher'):
                popup(title: "", message: "", buttonText: "", show: $showPopup).onReceive($viewModel.vmShowPopup){show in showPopup = show}
                
            }
        }
    }
```

It seems to me that I took a wrong approach, but I don't know how to implement it in the MVVM style. I would be very happy if someone could help me.

Thank you in advance and kind regards,
Victor

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: we don't use MVVM in SwiftUI, just use @State var showPopup that's all you need. The View struct is already a view model for the UIViews that SwiftUI creates/updates based on the values of the struct.